# async fs.stat java scipt

Tags: javascript, node.js

i'm new in programming, and i have tough times with async. Here i'm trying to get birth time of every file in directory.

```
async getAllFiles(req, res, next) {
    let allFiles = []

    fs.readdir(directoryPath, function (err, files) {
      if (err) {
        console.error(err)
        res.status(400).send({
          message: 'Bad request',
        })
      }
      files.forEach(async (file) => {
        const filePath = directoryPath + '/' + file
        const birthtime = await fs.stat(filePath, function (err, stats) {
          stats.birthtime
        })
        allFiles.push({ file: file, birthtime: birthtime })
      })

      res.status(200).send(allFiles)
    })
  },
```

i was rewriting this code in different ways but the all didn't work so i just gave up

Comment: Trying doing -> `for (file of files) {` instead of `files.forEach`,  `forEach` doesn't work they way you think with `async / await`..

Comment: Switch to [`node:fs/promises`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#promise-example) dealing with asynchronous stuff in loops becomes *much* simpler when using `await` instead of callbacks.